# Non reliably repeatable error in tidyr::separate() 'embedded nul string in' vexing

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a very simple piece of code that is trying to separate a ':' separated column text to multiple additional columns.

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(stringr)

   df <- df %>%
      mutate(rowCsvText = str_replace_all(rowCsvText, ',', '')) %>%
      separate(
        rowCsvText,
        into = c('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9'),
        sep = ':', fill = 'right'
        )
```

Unfortunately, I randomly get an error like this when I run this piece of code on the text I have:

```
Error in stringi::stri_split_regex(value, sep, n_max) :
  embedded nul in string: '\xf8q\xc5\0\0'
```

Then, when I re-run the same exact piece of code again on the same exact source data frame, the code works and produces the desired output. I have not had it fail on the second try.

Any idea what might be going on?

My data looks something like this:

```
                                               rowCsvText
                                                    <chr>
1  1:88,123,142:3.85:97.91:2.09:26,613:100.00:94.14:36.00
2  2:82,248,278:3.82:97.90:2.10:24,839:100.00:94.31:36.03
3  3:97,724,219:3.99:97.98:2.02:29,513:100.00:94.04:35.98
4  4:91,130,505:3.87:97.91:2.09:27,521:100.00:94.08:35.99
5 1:133,027,642:5.81:97.55:2.45:40,174:100.00:93.65:35.90
6 2:126,668,919:5.88:97.57:2.43:38,254:100.00:93.88:35.94
```

I understand this is not a re-producible example, and I can't think of how to give one for this problem. Writing the df to a file, re-reading and running the code works fine.